# Unable to refer Global Data in nunjunks

Tags: lightning-web-runtime

I am trying to create a custom LWR site when trying to refer Global Data in the nunjunks template.

Currently it doesn’t show any result.

My current site setup.

```
src/
  └── data/     
      ├── site/
      │   └── navbar.json
      └── global.json

global.json
{
    "author": "Jaydeep Godara",
    "site": "My Site"
}


lwr.config.json
{ 
   "cacheDir": "$rootDir/__lwr_cache__",
   "contentDir": "$rootDir/src/content",
   "layoutsDir": "$rootDir/src/layouts",
   "globalDataDir": "$$rootDir/src/data",
   //Addition config.
}


Blog.njk
---
someText: Good to meet you
---

Page URL {{ page.url }}

Author {{ global.author }}
{{ someText }}
```

Here It's rendering "page" and "someText" context info but not global data "author".

Am I missing anything here?

Doc I referred to configure this [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwr/guide/lwr-compile-data.html).

Answer (score 0):

Dumb me was passing $$ in globalDataDir path.

```
"globalDataDir": "$$rootDir/src/data",
```

Fix version:

```
"globalDataDir": "$rootDir/src/data",
```

**LWR throws PATH errors for "contentDir" and "layoutsDir" but not for "globalDataDir".**